# How to mention attribute(?attr) inside ternary operator in android data binding?

Tags: android, data-binding

**It's boolean data**

```
  <variable
                name="isSelected"
                type="boolean" />
```

This is how I tried to change background color of view based on selection, In my case I should change textviews colour, background colours and icon colours based on selection.

**This is what I tried** but I am getting error in Android studio.

```
        android:backgroundTint="@{isSelected ? ?attr/colorPrimaryVariant : ?attr/colorPrimary}"
```

It's an error

```
<expr> expected, got '?'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it is still relevant. I faced the same issue and found the solution.

1. You should import your `R` class

`<import type="com.example.test.R" />`

2. Now, you can use theme attribute in the expression

`"@{isSelected ? R.attr.colorPrimaryVariant : R.attr.colorPrimary}"`

3. It also requires creating `BindingAdapter` because without it will crash

Something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("backgroundAttr")
fun setBackgroundAttr(view: View, @AttrRes color: Int) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(MaterialColors.getColor(view, color)
}
```

4. So in XML, it will look like this

`app:backgroundAttr="@{isSelected ? R.attr.colorPrimaryVariant : R.attr.colorPrimary}"`

Comment: Yes It's relevant, might be useful for other developers